# How to access RESTlet SuiteScript parameters using GET method

Tags: javascript, rest, netsuite

I was stuck on a problem which probably plenty of new SuiteScript *hackers* will.

As writted on the [official doc of SuiteScript](https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=5732122&c=NLCORP&h=5fca4bf5dd825a28ab41&_xt=.pdf&addrcountry=US) p. 243, there's this JS for retrieve a record with GET method.

```
// Get a standard NetSuite record
function getRecord(datain) {
    return nlapiLoadRecord(datain.recordtype, datain.id); // e.g recordtype="customer", id="769"
}

//  http://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=22&deploy=1&recordtype=customer&id=769
```

But, when I was trying the **EXACT** snippet on NetSuite side, `datain.recordtype`was undefined. (and return should only return text, BTW.)

Fortunately, I've found the solution by myself. Check my answer below.

Comment: I'm glad this Q/A has helped someone at least. My time wasn't wasted!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### In this snippet (the same as above) ...

```
function getRecord(datain) {
    return nlapiLoadRecord(datain.recordtype, datain.id); // e.g recordtype="customer", id="769"
}

//  http://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=22&deploy=1&recordtype=customer&id=769
```

—

SuiteScript was filling `datain` not as an object nor JSON but as a *string* (for reason I still ignore.)

What you have to do so is just **parse it** before, then access the JSON with dot notation.

```
function getRecord(datain) {
    var data = JSON.parse(datain); // <- this
    return "This record is a " + data.recordtype + " and the ID is " + data.id;
}

//  http://rest.na1.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=22&deploy=1&recordtype=customer&id=769
```

*I've changed the return statement in the solution because SuiteScript gives me error when I try to return something what isn't a text.*

#### OR

As [egrubaugh360](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2387970/egrubaugh360) said, specify the `Content-Type` is `application/json` on your query script (the one who make call to your SuiteScript script)

So it'll give something like this if you're dealing with Node.js like me :

```
var options = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "<insert your NLAuth Authentification method here>",
        "Content-Type" : "application/json" // <- this
    }
}

https.request(options, function(results) {
    // do something with results.
}
```

Hope this will help someone.

Comment: I believe this entirely depends on what type of request you were sending to the RESTlet in the first place. If you send a request with a `Content-Type` of `text/plain`, then yes, `datain` will be a String. If you send an `application/json` request, then you *should* get an Object. Those are the only two acceptable `Content-Types` for a RESTlet (unfortunately).